# Can I use Azure Functions within ExpressRoute?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function under an ExpressRoute subscription that is trying to connect to an on-prem database, but fails to do so.
Is it possible to use Azure functions within ExpressRoute?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Azure Function can be deployed on an **[App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-environment/intro)**. The App Service Environment is deployed on your own VNET which can have access to on-prem resources via **ExpressRoute**.

If you don't want to pay for an App Service Environment, you can deploy your Function on a dedicated **[App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan)** and then use **[Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/biztalk-services/integration-hybrid-connection-overview)** to connect to on-prem, or integrate the Function App to your **VNET** and create a **Site-to-Site VPN to on-premises**. These last 2 options option, however, won't go through ExpressRoute.

All 3 options are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet). You just need to deploy your Azure Function to an App Service Plan to get same features as an App Service.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Not without setting up a dedicated router virtual appliance (e.g. a CiscoASA VM from the Azure marketplace). Microsoft will say "not supported", but we were able to get it working in this manner.